# System Control Registers in ARM Cortex-A7

Tags: assembly, arm, cpu-architecture, armv7

When **MCR** or **MRC** instructions execute with different **cRm** or **opt2**, then what is the status of **cRn** register?
For example if run:

```
asm volatile("mcr p15, 0, %0, c9, c13, 0" : : "r"(val))
```

or

```
asm volatile("mcr p15, 0, %0, c9, c13, 2" : : "r"(val))
```

then, which register's value will be changed **c9** or **c13**? and what is the role of last option(0 or 2)?.[here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0464f/BABFIBHD.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MCR and MRC instructions are generic coprocessor instructions. What these instructions do depends on the particular hardware you're using, what coprocessors it has, and the values of the opcode and coprocessor register operands (*opcode1*, *opcode2*, *CRn* and *CRm*).  The coprocessor register operands don't necessarily refer to actual coprocessor registers, and so are effectively additional opcode operands.

To find out what an MCR/MRC nstructions does, you need to look up it up in the hardware specific documentation the particular CPU this code is meant to run under. So with your examples we need to look in the [Cortex-A7's documentation for coprocessor 15](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0464d/BABHBIDJ.html), which is the System Control "coprocessor". This page lists the System Control registers that can be accessed using these instructions in *CRn*, *opcode1*, *CRm*, *opcode2* order.

In both your examples *CRn* is c9, and looking that up in the documentation leads to us to [a page describing mostly performance monitoring related registers](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0464d/BABFIBHD.html). In your first example *opcode1* is 0, *CRm* is 13, and *opcode2* is 0, which this page tells us that the instruction writes to the PMCR or Performance Monitor Control Register. With the second example *opcode1* is 0, *CRm* is 13, and *opcode2* is 2, meaning it accesses the PMNCNTENCLR or Count Enable Clear Register.

Comment: beat me slightly. :-)

Comment: So, we can say, there is nothing like registers cRn, cRm these are just addresses to PMCR or Count Enable Clear register etc in the core. right?
and for accessing these registers we need instructions (mcr/mrc), according to hw specific documentation..

Comment: @enfinet Basically every operand other than the ARM register operand is a number that needs to be looked up in a table in order to find out what the instruction does.

Answer (score 3):

You're better off thinking that op1, op2, crn and crm form a certain register address. The latter instruction sets the co-processor 15 register 0, c9, c13, 2 (PMXEVCNTR, Performance Monitors Event Count Register) to the value contained in the register the C compiler decides to use for variable 'val'.

For other than performance counter registers:
B3.17.1        CP15 register summary by coprocessor register number
                     Figure B3-26 summarizes the grouping of CP15 registers by primary coprocessor register number for a VMSAv7
                     implementation.

```
                 CRn      opc1         CRm           opc2
                  c0      {0-2}        {c0-c7}       {0-7}      ¶    ID registers
                  c1      {0, 4}      {c0, c1}       {0-7}           System control registers
                  c2      {0, 4}      {c0, c1}       {0-2}               Memory protection and
                  c3        0            c0            0                 control registers
                  c5      {0, 4}       {c0,c1}       {0,1}               Memory system
                  c6      {0, 4}         c0        {0, 2, 4}             fault registers
                  c7      {0, 4}      Various      Various      ¶    Cache maintenance, address translations, miscellaneous
                  c8      {0, 4}      Various      Various           TLB maintenance operations
                  c9      {0-7}       Various        {0-7}      ¶    Reserved for performance monitors and maintenance operations
                 c10      {0-7}       Various        {0-7}      ¶    Memory mapping registers and TLB operations
                 c11      {0-7}     {c0-c8,c15}      {0-7}      ¶    Reserved for DMA operations for TCM access
                 c12      {0, 4}       {c0,c1}       {0,1}      ¶    Security Extensions registers, if implemented
                 c13      {0, 4}         c0          {0-4}      ¶    Process, context, and thread ID registers
                 c14      {0-7}       {c0-c15}       {0-7}      ¶    Generic Timer registers, if implemented
                 c15      {0-7}       {c0-c15}       {0-7}      ¶    IMPLEMENTATION DEFINED registers

                       Read-only              Read/Write             Write-only      ¶     Access depends on the implementation

               Figure B3-26 CP15 register grouping by primary coprocessor register, CRn, VMSA implementation
```

About debug registers, there is a description:
C6.4.1      Using CP14 to access debug registers
                  Accesses to registers that are visible in the CP14 interface generally use the following coprocessor instructions:
                  •     MRC for read accesses.
                  •     MCR for write accesses.

```
              In addition, the following coprocessors instructions are defined for specific registers accesses:

              MRRC            Read access to the Debug ROM Address Register, DBGDRAR, and the Debug Self Address Offset
                              Register, DBGDSAR, in an implementation that includes the Large Physical Address Extension.

              STC             Read access to the Host to Target Data Transfer Register, DBGDTRRXint.

              LDC             Write access to the Target to Host Data Transfer Register, DBGDTRTXint.


              Form of MRC and MCR instructions
              The form of the MRC and MCR instructions used for accessing debug registers through the CP14 interface is:

                      MRC p14, 0, <Rt>, <CRn>, <CRm>, <opc2>          ; Read
                      MCR p14, 0, <Rt>, <CRn>, <CRm>, <opc2>          ; Write

              Where <Rt> refers to any of the ARM core registers R0-R14. Use of R13 is UNPREDICTABLE in Thumb and
              ThumbEE states, and is deprecated in ARM state. <CRn>, <CRm>, and <opc2> are mapped from the debug register
              number as shown in Figure C6-1

              The use of the MRC APSR_nzcv form of the MRC instruction is permitted for reads of the DBGDSCRint only. Use with
              other registers is UNPREDICTABLE. See CP14 interface 32-bit access instructions, required in all versions of the
              Debug architecture on page C6-2124 for more information.

              For accesses to the debug registers, <CRn> <= 0b0111 and therefore bit[10] of the value in the figure is 0.

                                                                                       10 9     8    7   6   5    4   3     2    1   0
                                                                                Value 0              Register number[9:0]



                                                                           Arguments      CRn[3:0]       opc2[2:0]        CRm[3:0]


                                 Figure C6-1 Mapping from debug register number to CP14 instruction arguments
```